# Visual Studio - Configure Startup Projects

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution which includes a WebSite, a few Code Libraries, a WCF Service and a project that hosts the WCF service, which is basically just a web application with a .svc file in it.
The problem is that when i run the website, both the WCF Service and the WCF service start on two different ports. I would need only the WCF Service host to start, as that's the one i'm using. Any idea on how i can configure which project starts when i run the web site?